# How are data types interpreted, calculated, and/or stored?

Tags: python

In python, suppose the code is:

```
import.math

a = math.sqrt(2.0)

if a * a == 2.0:
    x = 2
else:
    x = 1
```

Comment: I have supposed the code provided. Thank you for the additional thought ;-) Do you have a question?

Comment: posted by accident, I'm so sorry. My question I meant to type is, why is the correct answer x = 1? From my understanding squaring the sqrt of 2.0 will just return 2.0.

Comment: Floating point numbers have a restricted precision so `a * a` isn't _exactly_ `2.0`

Comment: You can read more about this [here](http://0.30000000000000004.com/)

Comment: @StefanParenta If it was posted by accident, please edit the question directly to make it clearer.

Answer (score 2):

This is a variant of "Floating Point Numbers are Approximations -- Not Exact".

Mathematically speaking, you are correct that sqrt(2) * sqrt(2) == 2.  But sqrt(2) can **not** be exactly represented as a native datatype (read: floating point number).  ([Heck, the sqrt(2) is actually guaranteed to be an infinite decimal!](https://www.math.utah.edu/~pa/math/q1.html)). It can get really close, but not exact:

```
>>> import math
>>> math.sqrt(2)
1.4142135623730951
>>> math.sqrt(2) * math.sqrt(2)
2.0000000000000004
```

Note the result is, in fact, *not* exactly 2.

If you want the `x = 2` branch to execute, you will need to use an *epsilon* value of "is the result close enough?":

```
epsilon = 1e-6    # 0.000001
if abs(2.0 - a*a) < epsilon:
    x = 2
else:
    x = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Numbers with decimals are stored as floating point numbers and they can only be an approximation to the real number in some cases.

So your comparison needs to be not "are these two numbers exactly equal (==)" but "are they sufficiently close as to be considered equal".

Fortunately, in the math library, there's a function to do that conveniently. Using isClose(), you can compare with a defined tolerance. The function isn't too complicated, you could do it yourself.

```
math.isclose(a*a, 2, abs_tol=0.0001)
>> True
```